# How to configure Spring Cloud logging?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, spring-cloud-aws

I have a Spring Boot application with Spring Cloud components, namely `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config`.

The component produces logs at WARN level when the application starts which I want to suppress.

Setting a log level in the `application.yml` like

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.cloud.aws.paramstore.AwsParamStorePropertySourceLocator: ERROR
```

did not work. Apparently its because this `cloud` component works at bootstrap time before the Spring Boot context starts and the `application.yml` is read.

How can I suppress this component logs in the best way?

Comment: what happens when you move the same configuration to `bootstrap.yaml`?